# Blockquote description in Markdown help

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, blockquote, editing-help

I think the description of "blockquote" https://cs.stackexchange.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes is confusing. It doesn't explain what blockquote should be used for and instead says

> You don't need to hard-wrap the paragraphs in your blockquotes, but it looks much nicer if you do

which makes it sound like something we should use for paragraphs (e.g. it happens [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/149195/in-programming-data-types-size-are-depends-upon-what)).

Comment: As for "You don't need to hard-wrap the paragraphs in your blockquotes, but it looks much nicer if you do" – well, it's probably not very clearly explained there, but what it means is that when you're using blockquote formatting on a whole paragraph, you don't *need* to hit Enter and write `> ` at the end of each row of text in the paragraph (since the editor will automatically handle [line-breaking/word-wrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_wrap_and_word_wrap) for text longer than what would fit in a single line)... But it looks nicer if you do so.

Comment: (And using the blockquote button in the editor – or the corresponding hotkey, Ctrl+Q – will automatically do that for you.)

Comment: ...That said, if you want to suggest 2 totally different changes to 2 totally different parts of the Markdown editing help page, I'd suggest making a separate post for each change – so you could edit this MSE post to focus just on the confusing wording for the "blockquote" section, and then make a new post regarding the link for the "LaTeX" section (which only appears on some sites – so if this issue only affects the CS.SE version of the page, the Meta for that site may be a better place to make that post; site mods can escalate issues from their Meta site by adding the [status-review] tag).